# I am getting one error and I don't know how to fix it

Tags: c#, asp.net

I get an Error on this line of code:

```
CurrentPage = FillRepeater() – 1;
```

For paging purpose i use `PagedDataSource` class, which is the same class used for paging in other databound controls.In `FillRepeater()` function, I created the object of the `PagedDataSource` class and used some of its methods.After this simple  property used to get the current page value as follows. This simply:

1. Uses the `viewstate` to store the current state of the Data page
2. And also I will add functionality to linkbutton which gets First,
   Last, Previous and Next page on click event.

Below is the Code:

```
public partial class ExamPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{

SqlConnection con;
string query;


public ExamPage()
{
    con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();

}


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private int FillRepeater()
{
    query = "select top 10 Question,Option1,Option2,Option3,Option4 from Questions";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    con.Open(); SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    da.Fill(ds);

    PagedDataSource pds = new PagedDataSource();
    pds.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    pds.AllowPaging = true; pds.PageSize = 8;

    int count = pds.PageCount;
    pds.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPage;

    if (pds.Count > 0)
    {

        lbtnPrev.Visible = true;
        lbtnNext.Visible = true;
        lbtnFirst.Visible = true;
        lbtnLast.Visible = true;

        lblStatus.Text = "Page " + Convert.ToString(CurrentPage + 1) + "of" + Convert.ToString(pds.PageCount);

    }

    else {

        lbtnPrev.Visible = false;
        lbtnNext.Visible = false;
        lbtnFirst.Visible = false;
        lbtnLast.Visible = false;

    }

    lbtnPrev.Enabled = !pds.IsFirstPage;
    lbtnNext.Enabled = !pds.IsLastPage;
    lbtnFirst.Enabled = !pds.IsFirstPage;
    lbtnLast.Enabled = !pds.IsLastPage;

    Repeater1.DataSource = pds;
    Repeater1.DataBind();

    return count;

}
public int CurrentPage
{
    get
    {
        object obj = this.ViewState["_CurrentPage"]; if (obj == null) { return 0; }
        else
        {
            return (int)obj;

        }

    }

    set

    {

        //set in viewstate the current page number

        this.ViewState["_CurrentPage"] = value;

    }
}

protected void lbtnPrev_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    CurrentPage -= 1;

    FillRepeater();

}

protected void lbtnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    CurrentPage += 1;

    FillRepeater();

}

protected void lbtnFirst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    CurrentPage = 0;

    FillRepeater();

}

protected void lbtnLast_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    CurrentPage = FillRepeater() – 1;

    FillRepeater();

}
}
```

I am getting syntax error not run-time error but I don't know how to solve it. Please tell me where I am making mistake

Comment: Can you share more details about what error you are getting? Line number, type of error, etc?

Comment: Something is wrong with the `–`, its not the minus sign. Replace it.

Answer (score 0):

```
CurrentPage = FillRepeater() – 1;
```

In that line, the `–` character is the [en dash](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm). Most programming languages only allow you to use the [hyphen-minus](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d/index.htm), `-`, to represent subtraction. The hyphen-minus key is present on most keywords.

```
CurrentPage = FillRepeater() - 1;
```

The reason why you have an en dash in your code is that it was probably authored using a word processing software, such as Microsoft Word, which automatically converts the hypen-minus to an en dash when the next word is followed by a space.

Comment: yes, You were right. The problem is with the minus sign only. I corrected my mistake...but the output I am getting is something that is not expected i.e last question of every page is display below the label.This happens every time when I move next,first,last and previous page..I don't know why